# How to parse AzureHttpError in python

Tags: python, azure

This is the content of exception which I get from azure ( where exception if of type azure.common.AzureHttpError in python):

`Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:a8ecea4d-001e-0112-76b0-9a717b000000
Time:2018-01-31T16:31:20.9812336Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature did not match. String to sign used was masking_it_intentionally
rwdlacup
bfqt
sco
2018-01-03T21:19:36Z
2018-03-09T05:19:36Z
https
2017-04-17
</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>`

It seems that the body of exception is some string, followed an xml styled chunk of information. I would like to extract a particular key from the xml data , for ex. `AuthenticationErrorDetail`  ( so that I can write some code based on it's value )

I want to do it in the easiest way i.e. I don't wan't to parse the exception body myself. Because if I decide to parse the xml myself, how would I decide where the xml is beginning from ? ( Yes , I can search for string `<?xml`, but I want to avoid it ).

So, how can I do it ?

I am hoping that there would be already some library/tool/parser/object for achieving this.

Comment: Hi,do you just want to find a parser to extract key values from the xml file?

Comment: Hi, any updates?

Comment: Nope . No update. So I have finally decided to parse the exception message myself ( using re ).  Seems very unprofessional, but thats the only option I have now.

Answer (score 0):

`AzureHttpError` has some attributes you can use: `status_code`, `error_code` and `args`. The first two are probably the most useful for your purposes. I check those are what I expect and otherwise rethrow the error.

```
try:
    # try something
except AzureHttpError as err:

    if err.status_code == 409 and err.error_code == 'BlobAlreadyExists':
                print('Blob already exists.')
            else:
                raise err
```

I don't know if this is the best way, I couldn't find anything in the documentation so figured it out using `err.__dict__` and `err.__dir__()`, but it works and is certainly better than parsing the error string.